# In VSTS, can I specify the new state of a linked work item when a pull request is approved?

Tags: azure-devops

Once the PR is approved I want to automatically advance the state of the linked work item, but I don't want it to be marked as "complete". Instead I'd like the work item state to be "ready for testing" (still in progress).

Answer (score 1):

For now, work item state can only be changed as complete when merging a PR.

And there has an user voice [Customize Work Item State after PR is closed](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20166982-customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed) which suggests this feature, you can vote and follow up.

The work around for now is changing the linked work item(s) through CI build (after completing the PR). Detail work flow as follow:

- Add a CI build to trigger automatically after the target branch has new commit(s). And add a PowerShell task to update the linked work items state by [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-a-field).
- When PR is completed, CI build will be triggered automcally. And the linked work items state will be updated.

Comment: Thank Marina - that's not the answer I was hoping for, but it's a good answer. We'll build a custom step into our CI build to handle the state change.

Comment: Since the feature is not available for now, so you should temporarily use workaround(s) currently.

Comment: The user voice link no longer works. The new feature request can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365704/customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed.html)

Comment: To change the state of work items, I can recommend using [Blue Basher WorkItem Updater](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater). It is an Azure Pipelines task, ready to use without needing custom PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

- Add a rule to a work item type
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops
- Create service hook and cosume it later using azure function or logic app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops